# What is the problem in my sort algorithm?

Tags: assembly, mips

I wrote a function `max` which takes the max value of a list and saves its address in `$v0` and the value in `$v1`.
I also wrote a function `swap` to swap the values between two addresses
and another function which simply prints values in `$a0` and `$a1`.

Now I will sort the values in a list from lowest to biggest value.
For that I'm using the `sort` function which I gave the start address in `$a0` and the end address in `$a1`.
My idea is:

1. I use `max`
2. I put address of max into `$a0`
3. I swap the values between `$a0` and `$a1`
4. I put into `$a0` the start address of `list1` again

Here is where my problem is. I tried so many different things but I don't get it, and I really don't understand where the problem is.

5. I want to substitute by the address inside of `$a1, 4`
   then sorting the smaller list again
   until the addresses in `$a0 == $a1`
6. Jump to sorted.

```
    .data
list:   .word 9, 8, 7, 3, 6, -4, 3, -1
list1:  .word 2, 5, 33, 4, 77, 22, 345, 88, 7, 99
list2:  .word 3, 5, 444, -4, 357, 23452, 1, -4588, 45, 38
list3:  .word 3, 345, 33, -43, -37, -34522, 1, -88, 5, 8
n:  .asciiz "\n"
    .text


main:

    la  $a0     list
    la  $a1     list+28 

    jal     print
    jal     swap
    jal     print


#######--------------------------------Start searching biggest Value in list1 list2 list3-----------------#########################

    la  $a0     list1
    la  $a1     list1+120
    jal     max
    add     $a0 $v1 $zero
    li  $v0 1
    syscall
    la  $a0 n
    li  $v0 4
    syscall

    ###-----sort---####


    la  $a0 list1
    la  $a1 list1+36
    j   sort
sorted: 

    li  $v0     10
    syscall
swap:

    lw  $t0     ($a0)
    lw  $t1 ($a1)
    sw  $t0     ($a1)
    sw  $t1     ($a0)   
    jr  $ra





max:

    lw      $t0 ($a0)
    la  $v0 ($a0)
    lw  $v1 ($a0)

do: 

        lw  $t4 ($a0)
    slt $t1 $t0 $t4         
    bgtz    $t1 change              
    la  $a0 4($a0)          
    beq $a0 $a1 finish          
    j   do

change: 

        lw  $t0 ($a0)
    la  $v0 ($a0)
    lw  $v1 ($a0)
    la  $a0 4($a0)
    j   do

finish: 

         jr $ra





print:

    la $t0 ($a0)    
    lw $a0 ($a0)
    li $v0 1
    syscall
    la $a0 n
    li $v0 4
    syscall
    lw $a0 ($a1)
    li $v0 1
    syscall
    la $a0 n
    li $v0 4
    syscall
    la $a0 ($t0)        
    jr $ra




sort:   

    jal max
    move    $a0 $v0
    jal swap
    jal     print

    la  $a0 list1
    sub $a1 4

    beq $a0 $a1  sorted
    j   sort
```

Comment: Please properly format your code as code

Comment: "I tried so many different things but I don't get it." Please be more specific what you "don't get". This program is small enough that you should be able to step through it line by line.

Comment: ive all ready found the bug. there was no beq order at label change:

Comment: @R.aj Then please answer your own question. This is both permitted and encouraged, for the benefit of all the people who might find themselves in a situation similar to yours.